# Collector.of() arguments types are not resolved the way I want

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

### Collector.of(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R,T> accumulator, BinaryOperator<R> combiner, Function<R> finisher, Characterstics...)

```
    Collector<Integer, List<Integer>, List<Integer>> myCollector = 
            Collector.of(ArrayList<Integer>::new, 
                    (list, element) -> {list.add(element);}, 
                    (list1, list2) -> {list1.addAll(list2);},  
                    Function.identity();, 
                    Characteristics.values()
                    );
```

When I run the above code I expected the types used in the static function Collector.of() will be resolved but it wasn't. It invokes the following error in eclipse

> The method of(Supplier, BiConsumer, BinaryOperator,
>   Function, Collector.Characteristics...) in the type Collector is
>   not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList::new, (
>   list,  element) -> {}, ( list1,  list2) ->
>   {}, Function, Collector.Characteristics[])

I need help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a return value in the 3rd parameter (a `BinaryOperator` must have a return value):

```
Collector<Integer, List<Integer>, List<Integer>> myCollector = 
        Collector.of(ArrayList<Integer>::new, 
                (list, element) -> {list.add(element);}, 
                (list1, list2) -> {list1.addAll(list2); return list1;}, 
                                                    //  -------------   added 
                Function.identity(), 
                Characteristics.values()
                );
```

You also had an extra `;` after `Function.identity()`.

Comment: Of course, specifying `Characteristics.values()`, i.e. all existing characteristics (and even possibly new ones in the future), makes no sense. And since it includes `CONCURRENT`, this collector is already broken today. Further, it’s just re-inventing the `toList()` collector.

Comment: `Collector.of(ArrayList::new, List::add,.....` and as @Holger points out precisely, this really does nothing other than adding all `Characteristics` to the current `toList()` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Basically two issues -

1. A syntax error you are having, after `Function.identity()` you can't have `;`.
2. Third parameter is missing which is a `return` value.